# How to create, use and run the tutorials from "The Java EE 6 Tutorial" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

[The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) references java ee example projects available through the java ee 6 sdk update tool. The tutorial is oriented towards users of NetBeans and not Eclipse, but NetBeans is not an option for me.
I am new to Java EE and don't know how to take these samples and make an eclipse project from them.

The reason I don't just create a project and copy in the source is that I don't know which eclipse template or project structure I should use for each sample.

So, what should I do with these sample projects to get them up and running in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided there is a [Required Software](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gexaj.html) section. Basically you would need to follow all those instructions except for where NetBeans IDE is concerned.

For Eclipse related configuration I would recommend the Eclipse (Helios) [online documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp). Indigo is the latest version of Eclipse but not all plugins support that version.

There is a section in the documention for creating enterprise applications:
[Creating an enterprise application project](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tjear.html)

After familiarising yourself with how enterprise projects are created within Eclipse you should be able to import the sample source applications used in the Java EE tutorial without too much hassle.

You would probably want to install the [GlassFish plugin for Eclipse](http://glassfishplugins.java.net) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have all the required software to run the Java EE tutorial:

1. Install latest Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers.
2. Install Maven Integration for Eclipse (M2E) plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace (Main Menu: Help -> Eclipse Marketplace).
3. Install Subclipse plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace.
4. Install Glassfish tools plugin for your Eclipse version. Eg: Glassfish tools for Luna.
5. Add Glassfish server to Eclipse.
6. Get the Java EE Tutorial code using the Glassfish Update Tool. In my case, the Glassfish Update Tool did not bring all the codes from the example, so I checked out the Java EE tutorial code from the SVN. (File -> Import -> SVN -> Checkout Project from SVN). Create a new repository location specifying the URL. Example URL: https://svn.java.net/svn/javatutorial~svn/trunk/example.
7. Ones you have the examples imported to an Eclipse workspace, you can build an individual example projects as follows:
8. From the Eclipse project explorer window select the project folder you want to build. Example: examples/web/jsf/hello1
9. Right click on the project folder and select import -> Maven -> Existing Maven projects option. Tick the option to add the project to your workspace.
10. From the project explorer window, now select the newly added project folder.
11. Now build the project using option Project -> Build project option.
12. After the successful build, run the application using Run -> Run As -> Run on Server option.

This worked for me. I had exactly the same question and being new to everything Eclipse, I had trouble figuring this out.